# sintaxis elif python

Tags: python-3.x

tengo este codigo:

```
x = int(input("Ingresa un entero, por favor: "))
if x < 0:
... x = 0
... print('Negativo cambiado a cero')
... elif x == 0:
... print('Cero')
... elif x == 1:
... print('Simple')
... else:
... print('Más')
```

y me marca un error de sintaxis en la linea de elif, de su ayuda para saber cual es, es en Python 3.7

Comment: Los `elif` deben estar alineados con el correspondiente `if`

Answer (score 2):

Python es un lenguaje orientado a código limpio y claro; bonito, podríamos decir. 
Si has notado, python no usa llaves, ni otros símbolos para anidar bucles o bloques de código. Esto es porque lo hace por medio de la [indentación o sangrado](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/Su_primer_programa_en_Python/Sangrado_(indentado)_de_c%C3%B3digo).

Para que ese código funcione simplemente tienes que poner las instrucciones dentro del nivel correspondiente

```
x = int(input("Ingresa un entero, por favor: "))
if x < 0:
    x = 0
    print('Negativo cambiado a cero')
elif x == 0:
    print('Cero')
elif x == 1:
    print('Simple')
else:
    print('Más')
```

Otra cosa, python soporta intentación con espacios y tabulaciones. Es más usual los espacios (4 espacios por nivel). Sin embargo es prohibitivo combinarlos, o son espacios, o son tabulaciones. Más información, [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)